# How do I send dates from a sharepoint list item to a sharepoint calendar?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, infopath

I've created a Change Management System in our SharePoint Online environment that involves InfoPath forms, SharePoint Designer workflows, and three separate SharePoint lists. My question is when a user goes to create a change management request and loads the first form I've added a Start Date and End Date field for them to select. When I added the Date/Time column to the list it only let me select a single date and so I had to create two columns.

What I'd like to know how to do is after the user fills out the form and selects a start and end date, how can I get that date info to transfer over to the SharePoint calendar on our team site?

Is there something I need to add to the workflow of that first list in order to accomplish that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a screenshot of what the first form looks like when a user creates a request.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with `When I added the Date/Time column to the list it only let me select a single date and so I had to create two columns`? Start date and end date would of course be two columns. A date field cannot hold more than one date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a workflow with SharePoint Designer that kicks off when a new item is created. Let the workflow create a new item in the team calendar. Use the start and end date and maybe the topic or similar to populate the new item in the team calendar.

Comment: Adding a Create List item for the Calendar to my workflow did the trick. Thank you teylyn.